# Webscraping Local web application, Trying to update the JSON object with Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, put

I am working on a project. I have a JSON object that has been pulled from a web scrape. The web is a html version of something I am working on to see current movies and if it is added to my watchedlist for IMDB. :

```
        {
         "title": "The Gallows Act II",
         "alternativeTitles": [],
         "secondaryYearSourceId": 0,
         "sortTitle": "gallows act ii",
         "status": "released",
         "overview": "When Ana Rue transfers to a prestigious 
new acting school, she encounters a                                           malevolent spirit after participating in a viral challenge.",
         "inCinemas": "2019-10-25T05:00:00Z",
         "physicalRelease": "2019-10-25T00:00:00Z",
         "physicalReleaseNote": "",
         "images": [
         {
         "coverType": "poster",
         "url": "/MediaCover/54956/poster.jpg"
         },
      {
        "coverType": "fanart",
        "url": "/MediaCover/54956/fanart.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "website": "",
    "year": 2019,
    "studio": "Tremendum Pictures",
    "profileId": 1,
    "pathState": "dynamic",
    "monitored": true,
    "minimumAvailability": "inCinemas",
    "isAvailable": true,
    "runtime": 99,
    "lastInfoSync": "2020-01-28T16:40:11.982967Z",
    "cleanTitle": "thegallowsactii",
    "imdbId": "tt7473716",
    "tmdbId": 505060,
    "titleSlug": "the-gallows-act-ii-505060",
    "genres": [],
    "tags": [],
    "ratings": {
      "votes": 12,
      "value": 5.3
    },
```

```
$address="http://localhost:PORT" 
$movie_id = ""
#$movie_title = Read-Host "Movie Title"
$params = @{"name"="RescanMovie";"movieId"="$movie_id";} | ConvertTo-Json
$apikey = 'APIKEY FOR APPLICATION'

$converted = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "$address/api/movie/" -Method GET/(10) -UseBasicParsing        -Header @{"X-Api-Key" = $apikey} 
$converted 
#$convertto = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "$address/api/movie/" -Method PUT -UseBasicParsing -Header    @{"X-Api-Key" = $apikey}
```

Now I pull this information with API pull : Invoke-Webrequest.

- I get the objects.
- I want to change the "Monitored" if it is on the list I want to change it to false or true respectively.
- I break the object down to initial search "Monitored" is -eq true.
- It pulls them in.
- I want to pull the JSON information for all fields" update the Monitored status to true or false if its found in the list. 
  -Then pass all fields back to the json object and updated it.

However. I am not sure how to perform the POST command in powershell to update the whole list passing it back.

Comment: Different APIs have different ways they want to receive data, assuming the API even supports it. Without documentation on the API, it's really difficult to provide any suggestions.

Comment: if it helps the situation the api documentation for the local application says i can perform the get function and update..
GET/{id}
Summary



---------------------------------

PUT
Summary

Update an existing movie
Parameters

Required: All parameters (you should perform a GET/{id} and submit the full body with the changes
Returns JsonObject

so this is the portion, its almost like I have to write to a file change, and then upload the entire entry. Just not sure how to get PShell to update the existing with all the same data except the one monitored field bool True/False